# How can send validation error to specific Html.ValidationSummary() if I have 2 forms in the page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 forms in the page in ASP.NET MVC 5

```
<form class="left" action="leftaction">
@Html.ValidationSummary()
</form>

<form class="right" action="rightaction">
@Html.ValidationSummary()
</form>
```

form.left is included by the template using @Html.Partial("ProfilePhotoPartial", vmLayout.ProfilePhotoViewModel)

ProfilePhotoViewModel has only one property string Image

form.right is using PostViewModel with 2 required properties Title and Content

My problem is that when I submit the form.right, it's validation errors will also display in the form.left. How can I make the validation errors display to form.right Html.ValidationSummary() only?

Comment: That means you must have inputs with duplicate `name` attributes in each form. What is the point of your view - you can only ever submit one form (and generating all that extra html makes no sense). What are you trying to do here?

Comment: thank you for your time, I made updates to my question

Comment: Dont use `ValidationSummary()` - use validation for each property - `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.yourProperty)`. But again, what are you trying to do - having 2 forms for this makes no sense.

Comment: The template has profile image at the left with input[type="file"] under it so user can easily click the input field below it and change the picture.

At the right is the action specific view, Post form, with title and content field

Comment: But you still need to 'post' the image - why are you not doing it in one form?

Comment: i just want to post form.right, unfortunately form.left (image form) is already part of the template. these 2 forms are expected to act independently. maybe i just need to change the implementation of the image instead of putting it in the form if 2 independent forms are not possible in one page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135345/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-heero-yuy).